# How to get the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ and check if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X \sim Binomial(1, 0.4)$ and $Y \sim Binomial(2, 0.4)$, respectively. Assume $P(X = 1, Y = 2) = 0$ and X and Y are uncorrelated. What is the joint probability of $X$ and $Y$? Also, how to find $P(X\le Y)$ ?

[That they are not independent. Because $P(X=1)P(Y=2)=0.4\times 0.4^2\neq 0$.]

---

I am confused about the question. Because it seems that the information is not enough to get the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$. We know that
$$
f_X(x)=0.4^x0.6^{1-x}, x=0, 1
$$
and
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{y(y-1)}{2}0.4^y0.6^{2-y}, y=0,1,2
$$

But how to get the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ and check if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Note neither $P(X=1)$ or $P(Y=2)$ are 0. What does this tell you about independence?

Comment: Also without having written out the details, you may try to use the fact $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ to gain information about the joint distribution.

Comment: @Jacobiman Yes. That they are not independent. Because $P(X=1)P(Y=2)=0.4\times 0.4^2\neq 0$.

Comment: @Jacobiman How to use that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ to get the joint pdf?

Comment: I agree with you that the information is not enough to get the joint pdf. And I don't think $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y].$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_{ij}$ denote $P(X=i, Y=j)$. The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated implies that their covariance is zero, which is the same as saying that $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$. But $E[XY]=p_{11}+2p_{12}=p_{11}$ so $p_{11}=E[X]E[Y]=0.32$. This gives you enough information to work out the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.